# How to properly implement operator<=> for a non-POD class?

Tags: c++, comparison, c++20, spaceship-operator

I'm looking for a way to implement the *three-way comparison operator* and the *operator==* for the following class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    auto operator<=>( const Foo& rhs ) const noexcept = default;

private:
    std::uint32_t m_Y;
    std::uint32_t m_X;
    char m_C;
    std::vector<char> m_Vec;
};
```

But the `default` implementation is not what I intended. Therefore I need to write my own implementation.

What I want is:

1. I want the *equality* comparison (`==` and `!=`) to be based on comparing the members `m_Y`, `m_X`, and `m_C` of two operands (of type `Foo`). All of those three members must be equal to satisfy the equality. The equality of the content of `m_Vec` is not important (since it's not efficient to compare all those elements lexicographically).
2. I want the *ordering* comparison (`<` and `>`) to be based on comparing the expression **`m_Y` * `m_X`**.
3. I want the *ordering* comparison (`<=` and `>=`) to be based on comparing the expression **`m_Y` * `m_X`** and if both operands are equal in that regard, then all three members of both operands should be equal to satisfy the `<=` or `>=` (just like in `==`).

Also with all this said, which comparison category type suits this scenario better, `std::strong_ordering` or `std::weak_ordering`?

How should I implement such logic? It seems simple and I read a whole recipe in a C++20 book on this topic and I still can't figure it out.

Comment: This seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: The reason you can't figure it out is because the stated requirements are contradictory. With the given requirements, `m_X=2` and `m_Y=3` will compare unequal to `m_X=3` and `m_Y=2`, but both `<` and `>` will evaluate to false, therefore they must be equal. As Mr. Spock would say: this is not logical. It is logically impossible to implement the operators this way.

Comment: The solution is to implement the individual operators, rather than try and shoehorn something into an operator that isn't meant for it. `operator<=>` is for the *non-Machiavellian* cases.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Yeah that scenario didn't come to my mind. What could be a logical way of doing it?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It is perfectly possible in a partial order. E.g. `0.0 < NaN` and `0.0 > NaN` are both `false`, but `0.0 == NaN` is also `false`. The standard `<=>` for `double` simply says `0.0` and `NaN` are `unordered`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is a partial order, which is an order where elements may be incomparable (none of `<`, `>`, or `==` hold between them). You should verify the necessary laws hold (`a <= b` iff `a < b || a == b`, `a <= a` for all `a`,  `a == b` if `a <= b && b <= a` for all `a`, `b`, and `a <= c` if `a <= b && b <= c` for all `a`, `b`, `c`). If that is the case, use `std::partial_ordering`.

```
std::partial_ordering operator<=>(Foo const &other) const noexcept {
    // compare your * expression first
    std::partial_ordering ret = (this->m_Y * this->m_X) <=> (other.m_Y * other.m_X);
    if(ret != 0) return ret;
    // if that's not informative, compare the fields
    return std::tie(this->m_Y, this->m_X, this->m_C) == std::tie(other.m_Y, other.m_X, other.m_C)
           ? std::partial_ordering::equivalent : std::partial_ordering::unordered;
}
```

Comment: Would it be problematic if I also implement `operator==`? I tried it and there was a condition in which `!=` is true and all of the ordering operators are false because <=> returns `partial_ordering::unordered`. Is this acceptable? I mean is it okay if **a != b** is true but **a < b** and **a <= b** and **a > b** etc return `partial_ordering::unordered`?